# Regarding tensorflow import error

Tags: python

while I was trying to import tensorflow the following error is creeping up

```
C:\Windows\system32>python
Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
 on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, descript
ion)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", lin
e 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-im
port
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.p
y", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_ten
sorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, descript
ion)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be with respect to TensorFlow trying to access GPU when the required CUDA version is not there on your machine like suggested here on [this Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13715)